# how to save listbox items in a text file

Tags: c#, listbox

I am using .Net 3.5 - I have a problem trying list box items to a text file.  I am using this code:

```
if (lbselected.Items.Count != 0) {
  string Path = Application.StartupPath + "\\ClientSelected_DCX.txt";
  StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path);
  int selectedDCXCount = System.Convert.ToInt32(lbselected.Items.Count);
  int i = 0;

  while (i != selectedDCXCount) {
    string selectedDCXText = (string)(lbselected.Items[i]);
    writer.WriteLine(selectedDCXText);
    i++;
  }

  writer.Close();
  writer.Dispose();
}

MessageBox.Show("Selected list has been saved", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

An error occurs for this line:

```
string selectedDCXText = (string)(lbselected.Items[i]);
```

The error is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'SampleData' to type 'System.String'
>   please help me

Answer (score 2):

Use `string selectedDCXText = lbselected.Items[i].ToString();`

Comment: Although he may want the whole object.

Comment: thanks it is saving but it is writing the list items to a text file its not saving the item names but saving this line in the text file  Realtime_ALL.Form1+SampleData Realtime_ALL.Form1+SampleData

Answer (score 0):

You should override ToString method in class, which instances you want to write into file. Inside ToString method you should format correct  output string:

```
class SampleData
{
   public string Name
   {
       get;set;
   }
   public int Id
   {
       get;set;
   }

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return this.Name + this.Id;
   }
}
```

And then use

```
string selectedDCXText = (string)(lbselected.Items[i].ToString());
```

Comment: thanks its working but besides that a 1 is added for every item like this ALUMINIUM - 1 MONTH 1 ,ALUMINIUM - 2 MONTH 1 ,ALUMINIUM - 3 MONTH 1 ,ATF - 1 MONTH1 1,ATF - 2 MONTH1 ,BRCRUDEOIL - 1 MONTH 1 ,how can i remove this 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Make sure that you have overridden the ToString method in your SampleData class like below:

                public class SampleData
{

                                // This is just a sample property. you should replace it with your own properties.
                                public string Name { get; set; }

                                public override string ToString()
                                {
                                    // concat all the properties you wish to return as the string representation of this object.
                                    return Name;
                                }

}

Now instead of the following line,
    string selectedDCXText = (string)(lbselected.Items[i]); 
you should use:
    string selectedDCXText = lbselected.Items[i].ToString();

Unless you have ToString method overridden in your class, the ToString method will only output class qualified name E.G. "Sample.SampleData"
```